# Calculate new array with bitmask from original array with NumPy (for optimization)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Python function that I want to improve. It calculates, from a given array, a new array with values based on the neighbours of each cell on the first array.

An example:

```
# 1: wall, 0: empty space
first_array = [
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
]
```

From this array, I want to fill a new array, where the values of the array are a bitmask:

```
Bit 1: wall at north
Bit 2: wall at south
Bit 3: wall at west
Bit 4: wall at east
```

The code is really simple:

```
for x in (1 .. 4):
    for y in (1 .. 3):
        if first_array[x, y] == 0:
            second_array[x, y] = 0
        else:
            # Calculate the bitmask
            bitmask = 0
            if first_array[x, y - 1] == 1:
                bitmask += 1
            if first_array[x, y + 1] == 1:
                bitmask += 2
            if first_array[x - 1, y] == 1:
                bitmask += 4
            if first_array[x + 1, y] == 1:
                bitmask += 8

            second_array[x, y] = bitmask
```

As you can see, the code is really simple... but slow. I know that this code can be improved with NumPy, creating arrays of 3x3 positions, and assign a value for each one of this arrays. But I don't know how it works, neither how to find this in the documentation. I know that exists the NumPy.select function; I suppose that I need something like this, but comparing arrays instead of just values as conditions. Can you help me with this?

Thank you!

EDIT: This should be the resulting array after the code:

```
second_array = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 5, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0,11,12, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
```

Maybe my explanation is not clear enough. What I want is, from a given array of walls (1) and empty spaces (0), fill a new array. In the new array, except the borders, I want that each cell **that has a wall in the first array**, have a number saying which of the 4 neighbour cells has walls.

The idea is to have 16 3x3 arrays with all the combinations of north, south, east and west walls, and use this arrays and NumPy to fill the second array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the example cannot works, many issues.
Anyway, in numpy the use of masks is very powerful and fast.
For your use cases, you can start from a central mask,

```
array[1:-1, 1:-1]
```

And move it 1 step up,right,down,left in order to create all combinations.

here a working example, for each layer of the mask you have a matrix

```
import numpy as np

# input array in np format
first_array = np.asarray([
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
], dtype=np.bool)


# center values, borders values are ignored
central_mask = first_array[1:-1,1:-1]

# And now all combinations
# starting from a bitmask of the same shape
upmask_array = np.zeros_like(first_array)
# applyng central mask in the proper position
upmask_array[:-2,1:-1] = central_mask

# and so on....
rightmask_array = np.zeros_like(first_array)
rightmask_array[1:-1,2:] = central_mask

# The same for left and bottom
```

At this point you can create your 'mask convention' i mean you can use directly the 4 *mask_array

Comment: Please, read again my explanation, because I've extended it. I think that the original text wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 2:
I tried your function but i didn’t get the same result :

```
 [[0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  6.  9.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. 14.  3.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

from this :
where x is the right size — here 6 —

```py
fa = np.array(first_array)
fb = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(fa, window_shape=(3,3)).reshape(x, 3, 3)
array([[[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1]]])
```

And you can try to multiply from here by a right matrix.
(I’m trying to do this next

the next :

```py
mask = np.array([[0,4,0], [1,1,2],[0,8,0]])
array([[0, 4, 0],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [0, 8, 0]])
np.multiply(fc, mask)
array([[[0, 4, 0],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [0, 8, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 8, 0]],

       [[0, 4, 0],
        [1, 0, 2],
        [0, 8, 0]],

       [[0, 4, 0],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 8, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

from here you have to select only the array that doen’t have a zero-center and sum it (we subtract 1 because the case in the center have a 1 into (with the sum))

```
np.where(fd[:,1,1] > 0, fd.sum(axis=(1,2)) - 1, 0)
```

EDIT: I see you want to keep the x/y shape : so

```
fa = np.array(first_array)
fb = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(fa, window_shape=(3,3)) 
fd = np.multiply(fb, mask)
final_array = np.where(fd[:,:,1,1] > 0, fd.sum(axis=(2,3)), 0)
```

```
array([[ 6, 9,  0],
       [ 0, 14,  3]])
```

EDIT 3:
I forgot to substract the one in the sum

And now, i have the same result than your first function

To explain what i do :

1. i setup some slicing window to select a square of value
2. i multiply this window by a mask
3. i sum and select the product to reproduce the shape
4. that’s all

Comment: I can devellop if you want

Comment: I can't understand what are you doing... Please, read again my explanation, because I've extended it. I think that the original text wasn't clear enough.